# How to fetch the data from SqLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I have created database in SqLite in my windows app, now I want to fetch the data from my database. This is the code how I inserted the data in databse.

```
var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "scrapbook.sqlite");
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
{
    // Create the tables if they don't exist 

    var bg = listAlbumContainer[0] as AlbumContainer;
    var albumbg = bg.BackgroundImageName;
    var sk = listAlbumContainer[0].listAlbumContainer;
    var _audio = listAlbumContainer[0].listAlbumContainer5;
    var _video = listAlbumContainer[0].listAlbumContainer3;
    var wa = listAlbumContainer[0].listAlbumContainer4;
    var ci = listAlbumContainer[0].listAlbumContainer2;
    var gi = listAlbumContainer[0].listAlbumContainer1;


    string snodesticker = Serializeanddeserializwhelper.Serialize(sk);
    string nodegi = Serializeanddeserializwhelper.Serialize(gi);
    string nodeci = Serializeanddeserializwhelper.Serialize(ci);
    string nodewa = Serializeanddeserializwhelper.Serialize(wa);
    string nodevideo = Serializeanddeserializwhelper.Serialize(_video);
    string nodeaudio = Serializeanddeserializwhelper.Serialize(_audio);


    var TittledataInsertCheck = db.Table<Title>().Where(x => x.ALBUM_TITLE.Contains(nametxt.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (TittledataInsertCheck == null)
    {
        db.Insert(new Title()
        {
            ALBUM_TITLE = nametxt.Text
        });

        var TittledataInsert = db.Table<Title>().Where(x => x.ALBUM_TITLE.Contains(nametxt.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (TittledataInsert != null)
        {
            db.Insert(new PAGE()
            {
                PAGE_BACKGROUND = albumbg,
                TITLE_ID = TittledataInsert.ID
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await new MessageDialog("Tittle Already Found Please change tittle").ShowAsync();
        return;
    }

    var PagedataInsert = db.Table<PAGE>().Where(x => x.PAGE_BACKGROUND.Contains(albumbg)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (PagedataInsert != null)
    {
        db.Insert(new CONTENT
        {
            PAGE_ID = PagedataInsert.ID,
            STICKERS = snodesticker,
            AUDIO = nodeaudio,
            VIDEO = nodevideo,
            GALLERY_IMAGES = nodegi,
            CAMERA_IMAGES = nodeci,
            WOARD_ART = nodewa
        });
    }

    db.Commit();
    db.Dispose();
    db.Close();
    var line = new MessageDialog("Records Inserted");
    await line.ShowAsync();
}
```

Is this the right way to insert the data?

I have a canvas on which I set the background image. And on this background some images, video and audio.

Comment: Did you had any issue with your code ? It is not obvious that something is not working from your sample. If you want to do everything "by hand" your code is one way of doing it. You can also use more advanced ORM to do all this work for you. You can have a look at entity framework core which is supporting SQLite databases on UWP applications. https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html

Comment: @vincent sir I want to know is this the right way to insert the data because in my data i have so many images video and audio. I have no issue with this code but I want to know that how to read or fetch the data now from database because dataset,dataeader and executereader is not working in sqlite like sql server database. and I am new in sqlite and uwp.

Comment: Are you saving the audio and video files into your database?

Comment: I save them in  local folder of application in database I have save path only